# Errors about non-ascii and Python libraryies when installing Anaconda3

Tags: python, anaconda

I have Python 3.6 install on my Windows 10 system. I want to install Anaconda3-4.3.0.1-windows-x86_64. But I got a error message when I select a path:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Pick a path that contains only ascii characters... like it says in the error message.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? I even change the path to like c:\anaconda. And I re-type in all the letters. still the same error.

Comment: Does your username contain non-ascii characters? It may be referring to the [PATH variable](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: Thanks. But I do not think this is the reason. Anyway, I am trying not to use Anaconda for now.